# Run script on /dev/tty access

Tags: shell-script, devices, tty

I have a remote serial device attached to `/dev/ttyAMA0` that requires a serial command to be issued before a program connects so that the program will read the return string and automatically recognize it. I can not change the behavior of the main program.

Is there any way to run a script when a userland program accesses a `/dev/tty` character device?

Adding a `udev` rule only runs during boot and not, say when I connect with minicom.

I was researching a way to make a fake character device that would do this but it was looking like I would need to write a device driver.

Comment: You need to more clearly explain what "access" is.  Because there's a significant difference between a program _on the machine_ opening a terminal device, and an external terminal (emulator) connecting to a serial device.

Comment: @JdeBP, updated the question

Comment: I don't completely understand who needs to issue a "serial command" to what, but would a program help that pipes between `/dev/ttyAMA0` and another pseudo tty, and does whatever initialization is required first? Then the userland program can access the pseudo tty slave instead of `/dev/ttyAMA0`. It's not hard to write such a program, look at `openpty`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up monitoring the log file and triggering the even when it wanted to connect.

`tail -f /tmp/lw.stdout.log | grep -q --line-buffered "INFO: Connecting to USB,/dev/ttyAMA0" && echo -n $'\cx' > /dev/ttyAMA0`